# Bhaskara sin function

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const float pi = 3.14159;
float sin, cos, tan, sec, csc, cot;

double x = 0.0;

sin = (16 * x * (pi - x)) / (5 * pi * pi - 4 * pi * (pi - x));
cos = (pi * pi - 4 * x * x) / (pi * pi + x * x);
tan = sin / cos;
sec = 1 / cos;
csc = 1 / sin;
cot = 1 / tan;

cout << "Enter radians: ";
cin >> x ;
cout << "The sin of " << x << " is: " <<endl;
cout << sin;

}
```

I'm basically trying to input a value 'x' and return the sin or etc of said number. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how I should format this to give me the correct number. I will eventually have the user select which function they want to use via else and if statements. any advice?

Comment: The code is run one statement at a time, top to bottom. All your calculations are done with `x` being zero.

Comment: so even when I put in a value for x after the first computer input, x is still zero?

Comment: First of all your denominator is incorrect. For the sine it should read `5 pi*pi -4x(pi-x)` and I would use doubles instead of floats and increase the precision of your constant pi. Only this way, your Bhaskara sine approximation will be good. Second, you should define them as functions, now they are just calculated with X equal to zero

Comment: @Kyronsk8 _"so even when I put in a value for x after the first computer input, x is still zero?"_ No, but it was at time you've done the calculations, and these won't be recalculated magically if the value of `x` changes.

Comment: ok I fixed denominator, thanks for catching that. I apologize for all the *'s as I have to show these for reasons.

Comment: ok so with all the feed back I think I should put each calculation in a nested if statement and call for x before the function is called. so I would ask for which function is to be used, then ask the user to input x, then have the log function under the cin input,

Answer (score 3):

You should probably try to define things in a modular way, so it's easier for you to reuse and test. As already noted in the comments, you should use doubles instead of floats. The reason for this is simple: `double`s have two times the precision of `float`s. A slightly more readable code for your program would look like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double bhaskaraSin(double x) {
  return (16 * x * (M_PI - x)) / (5 * M_PI * M_PI - (4 * x * (M_PI - x)));
}

double bhaskaraCos(double x) {
  return (M_PI * M_PI - 4 * x * x) / (M_PI * M_PI + x * x);
}

double bhaskaraTan(double x) {
  return bhaskaraSin(x) / bhaskaraCos(x);
}

// Similar for sec, csc and cot...

int main() {
  double x;
  cout << "Enter radians: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "The sin of " << x << " is: " << bhaskaraSin(x) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I would advise you to consider using a [switch-case](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) statement instead of if-else for letting the user decide which function to apply.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive response, I see that you're using the math header and I'm assuming that was for PI. The only thing I really need is the actual functions to be working. I only made the user part for testing the results of the functions. I am supposed to be creating these functions from scratch without using the math header file and merging them with my fellow class mates to create an extensive scientific calculator. I see that you made actual functions for them which is what I tried earlier today but failed. Again thank you.

Comment: also, `(16 * x * (M_PI - x)) / (5 * M_PI * M_PI - (4 * x * (M_PI - x)));`  seems to be giving incorrect values. I'm not sure why but I used `( 4 * x * (180 - x)) / (40500 - x * (180 - x));`